# jQuery Mobile: explicitly override the rounding of all corners

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, rounded-corners

jQuery Mobile automatically rounds all corners of input elements, by adding a class `ui-corner-all`. I noticed that if I change this class manually to `ui-corner-left` in Chrome inspector, then I correctly get *only* rounded corners on the left (top and bottom). This could of course easily be done with one line of jQuery, such as

```
$('#myid').removeClass('ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-corner-left');
```

My question is, is there a way I can instruct jQuery Mobile to apply this class straight away, without having to execute this extra bit of code after JQM has done it's work?

Comment: You could modify the JQM source code to replace one class with the other, or you could modify the JQM css to make ui-corner-all to work the way you want it. But I think your current solution should be fine. Why the concern about a single line of code? Have you seen how much JQM is already doing when the page loads? That one little bit of code shouldn't cause that much trouble.

Comment: Yes you are right - JQM is already running so much code that one line is not really going to make a difference in terms of performance. My real motivation is trying to keep UI things centralised and "declarative". But with this solution, my UI ends up being split not only between the CSS and the markup itself, but also between some odd bits of JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically following can be apply, but your concern is to run without extra  code execution, lets see wheter we get chance to get it, even I'm looking same question, but following is my solution.

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event){
     $('#myid').removeClass('ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-corner-left');
});
```

Comment: All you did was copy and paste the same code I wrote above; wrapping it in the `pageshow` handler is not relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default value by specifying in your index.html file the jquery mobile  class you want. A good example would be, instead of:

```
<ul id='myid' data-inset='true' data-theme='a' data-role='listview'  class='ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-shadow'>
```

which would automatically insert this

```
class ui-corner-all
```

you would then add your own class:

```
<ul id='myid' data-inset='true' data-theme='a' data-role='listview'  class='ui-listview ui-corner-left ui-listview-inset ui-shadow'>
```

In firefox, the ui-corner-all class does not get automatically added for me, maybe you are using an older version of jquery mobile and need to upgrade.
If you want to do it dynamically in a javascript file:

```
$("#my_page_id").live("pagecreate",function(){
    var ul = $("<ul id='myid' data-inset='true' data-theme='a' data-role='listview'  class='ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-left ui-shadow'>");
    ul.append($('<li class="ui-li ui-li-static  ui-body-a ui-corner-left">').append("Code Slayer!!!"));
    $('mydiv_in_mypage').html(ul);
```

});

as in re-write the contents of the div all over again, automatically erasing the old contents. If you will display a lot of information in your list you might want to use the

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg('a','Page Loading', true);
```

and then hide the message when your page has been fully displayed.

Answer (score 0):

hey Simply you can do like this

```
  <a  href="#panel"  data-corners="false"></a>
```